# Assume a Role from an Assumed Role

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have an AWS Lambda function which has an execution role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:<acc-no>:*",
                "arn:aws:iam::<acc-no>:role/myreportingrole"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:<acc-no>:log-group:/aws/lambda/<func-name>:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The execution role has permission to use STS AssumeRole to a role (myreportingrole) within the same AWS account that has trust relationships with roles in other AWS accounts.

I want to to assume myreportingrole and then assume a role in another account.

I have some Python code which successfully assumes myreportingrole and allows me to query services in the current account. However, when I try to assume a role from another account, I get a accessdenied error

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<acc-no>:assumed-role/<exec-role>/<func-name> is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<diff-acc-no>:role/roleX",
```

This is my Python code

```
import json
import boto3

def assume_local_role():
    sts_connection = boto3.client('sts')
    acct_b = sts_connection.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::<acc-no>:role/myreportingrole",
        RoleSessionName="lambdaTesting"
    )
    ACCESS_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
    SECRET_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
    SESSION_TOKEN = acct_b['Credentials']['SessionToken']
    
    client = boto3.client(
        'ec2',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
        aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN
    )
    return client

def assume_role():
    sts_connection = boto3.client('sts')
    acct_b = sts_connection.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::<diff-acc-no>:role/roleX",
        RoleSessionName="lambdaTesting"
    )
    ACCESS_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
    SECRET_KEY = acct_b['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
    SESSION_TOKEN = acct_b['Credentials']['SessionToken']
    
    client = boto3.client(
        'ec2',
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
        aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN
    )
    return client

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    client = assume_local_role() # Assumes myreportingrole
    client2 = assume_role() # Assumes roleX
    response = client2.describe_instances()
    print(response)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

The error shows that the execution role is being used to assume `RoleX`, which does not have permission.

I can't figure out how to use `myreportingrole` in `client2`. Normally on EC2, I would use `~/.aws/config and credentials`, however, being Lambda, I'm not sure if this is possible.

My understanding is that

```
`executionRole` assumes `myreportingrole`

credentials for `myreportingrole` then assumes `roleX`
```

However, what I'm getting is

```
`executionRole` assumes `myreportingrole`

`executionRole` assumes `roleX` and fails.
```

Is there a way to pass the credentials from `client` to `client2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you call the same client factory in both `assume_local_role()` and `assume_role()`. To use the local role to assume the remote role, you need to use the credentials from the first to create the client for the second. *Exactly like you're doing when creating the EC2 client.*

It would look something like this (I'm just typing this in, there may be syntax errors, and I've put a blank line between each function call to make the flow clear):

```
def create_client_with_remote_role(local_role_name, remote_role_name, client_type):

    local_assume_client = boto3.client('sts')

    local_assume_result = local_assume_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn=local_role_name,
        RoleSessionName="lambdaTesting")

    remote_assume_client = boto3.client('sts',
        aws_access_key_id=local_assume_result['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
        aws_secret_access_key=local_assume_result['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
        aws_session_token=local_assume_result['Credentials']['SessionToken'])

    remote_assume_result = remote_assume_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn=remote_role_name,
        RoleSessionName="lambdaTesting")

    return boto3.client(desired_client_type,
        aws_access_key_id=remote_assume_result['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
        aws_secret_access_key=remote_assume_result['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
        aws_session_token=remote_assume_result['Credentials']['SessionToken'])
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. My assumption was some form of AWS wizardry that handles credentials. It looks like passing the credentials to client2 will have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "trust" statement in the IAM Role definition used for the cross account role. You should also add a condition with an External ID, just to be safe. The below is similar:

```
AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
  Version: "2012-10-17"
  Statement:
    Effect: Allow
    Principal:
      AWS: <source-aws-account-id>
    Condition:
      StringEquals:
        "sts:ExternalId": <some-unique-identifier>
    Action:
      - "sts:AssumeRole"
```

Comment: myreportingrole has a trust relationship with roleX and the execution role is allowed to assume myreportingrole. Agreed on externalId, I kept it out whilst testing